# Why destructor isn't invoked?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


struct Foo {
    Foo() { std::cout << "Constructor ...\n"; }
    void doSth() {std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;}
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Destructor ...\n"; }
};


int main() {


   {std::weak_ptr<Foo> jack = (*(new std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo)));

    std::cout << (jack).use_count() << std::endl;
    // std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = jack.lock();
    // std::cout << ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The use_count() return value is 1, therefore I think the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object will be destroyed and the destructor will therefore be invoked. But it isn't the case. Can any guy explain why? If I want to maintain the structure like this: 
    new std::shared_ptr(new Foo)
and also have the destructor invoked, what should I do? 
The code is just written for fun, without any application background.

Comment: There is absolutely no point in dynamically allocating a `shared_ptr`, ever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bizarrely, you dynamically allocated the `shared_ptr`, and never did anything to destroy it. If the `shared_ptr` isn't destroyed, neither will be the thing it points to.

It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. You're writing strange, awkward code with no use case and wondering how to "make it work". Well to "make it work", write not-strange and non-awkward code. By definition that is the solution.

Comment: "bizarre" might be too weak ;)

Comment: Yep, I should destroy dynamically allocated shared_ptr like this: std::shared_ptr<Foo>* jack = new std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo); delete jack;  Well, I just explore around so the code looks awkward. Anyhow, your hint help me, though the question really sucks.

Comment: @Vito: Just don't dynamically allocate it in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"Just don't dynamically allocate it in the first place."_ Especially not without using a variable to hold the resulting pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> *"But it isn't the case. Can any guy explain why?"*

You're loosing the reference to the pointer created with the (sub) expression

```
new std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo))
```

and never call `delete` on it (or being even able to do so).

Hence it's own destructor and the destructor of the wrapped type never is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

> The use_count() return value is 1, therefore I think the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object will be destroyed and the destructor will therefore be invoked.

That is not true in this situation because you are **dynamically allocating** that `shared_ptr` and **never destroying it**.  `weak_ptr` does not destroy the `shared_ptr` it refers to.  And when you call `lock()` to get a new `shared_ptr`, the shared object's `use_count()` increments to 2, and then decrements to 1 when the `shared_ptr`from `lock()` goes out of scope, as expected. But the `use_count()` is still > 0 because the first `shared_ptr` is still hanging around in heap memory.  `shared_ptr` itself is not reference counted, you still have to allocate and destroy it like any other class.  It merely manages a reference count for the object it is sharing.

> If I want to maintain the structure like this: new std::shared_ptr(new Foo) and also have the destructor invoked, what should I do?

You have to explicitly `delete` the `shared_ptr` when you are done using it:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> *jill = new std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);

    {
    std::weak_ptr<Foo> jack = *jill;

    std::cout << jack.use_count() << std::endl;
    // std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = jack.lock();
    // std::cout << ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
    }

    delete jill;
    return 0;
}
```

Which completely defeats the purpose of `shared_ptr` in the first place.  You need to use it the way it was intended to be used:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> jill(new Foo);
    //std::shared_ptr<Foo> jill = std::make_shared<Foo>();

    std::weak_ptr<Foo> jack = jill;

    std::cout << jack.use_count() << std::endl;
    // std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = jack.lock();
    // std::cout << ptr.use_count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```